# How to know which line of code in Try block generates error

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

Currently I have a block of code with `try and catch`. In try block i have used some logic based on `IO and Database`, Now how to know that which line of code generates / getting an exception in try block for io or db related code.

Comment: You could debug and step?

Comment: I have used Multiple catch block related to IO and DB exceptions. Is there any another way to detect excetions...

Comment: Look at the exception stack trace?

Comment: You could check what type of Exception is thrown?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: use two try catches perhaps? divide your logic between them. Otherwise, *why* do you need to know which line throws the error?

Comment: Go to *Debug* - *Exceptions* and enable everything. Than the debuggers breaks before you step into the catch block at the correct line.

Comment: +1 for what @Jon said....Use Stack Trace.

Comment: Maybe you should think about using smaller and more *try* - *catch* blocks and/or explicitly declare the kind of exception each catch block can handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its Pretty Simple in .Net. In Your .Net Window Press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `E`. The Exceptions window will be opened. There you can see `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` Enable those two check boxes. You can get the Error line when ever the Exception is occurred. After pressing `F5` it will goes to `catch block`.